# Backup and restore some records of an elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I wish to take a backup of some records(eg latest 1 million records only) of an Elasticsearch index and restore this backup on a different machine. It would be better if this could be done using available/built-in Elasticsearch features.

I've tried Elasticsearch snapshot and restore (following code), but looks like it takes a backup of the whole index, and not selective records.

```
    curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -X PUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/es_data_dump?pretty=true" -d '
    {
      "type": "fs",
      "settings": {
        "compress" : true,
        "location": "es_data_dump"
      }
    }'

    curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -X PUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/es_data_dump/snapshot1?wait_for_completion=true&pretty=true" -d '
    {
      "indices" : "index_name",
      "type": "fs",
      "settings": {
        "compress" : true,
        "location": "es_data_dump"
      }
    }'
```

The format of backup could be anything, as long as it can be successfully restored on a different machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I fetched the required data using python driver because that is what I found the easiest for the given use case.

For that, I ran an Elasticsearch query and stored its response in a file in newline-separated format and then I later restored data from it using another python script. A maximum of 10000 entries are returned this way along with the scroll ID to be used to fetch next 10000 entries and so on.

```
es = Elasticsearch(timeout=30, max_retries=10, retry_on_timeout=True)
page = es.search(index=['ct_analytics'], body={'size': 10000, 'query': _query, 'stored_fields': '*'}, scroll='5m')
while len(page['hits']['hits']) > 0:
    es_data = page['hits']['hits'] #Store this as you like
    scrollId = page['_scroll_id']
    page = es.scroll(scroll_id=scrollId, scroll='5m')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use _reinex API. it can take any query. after reindex, you have a new index as backup, which contains requested records. easily copy it where ever you want.

complete information is here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html